# Spring Application - which logging framework is being used?

Tags: spring, logging, slf4j

I have a Spring application which I inherited.

The application contained some log4j.properties files, but these were obviously not in use, as changing these had no effect on log output.  The contents were trivial so I deleted them (relax, we have VCS).

The java classes all seem to use the slf4j "Logger" interface, but I know slf4j is just a facade that is calling a logging framework.

I'd like to configure the logging framework, but I don't know which one is in use, so experimenting by creating different config files in different locations is not getting me very far.

**How do I determine which logging framework is being used by this application?**

How do I determine which logging framework is actually in use?  There is a pom.xml which imports spring mvc but not spring boot.

It is virtually impossible to google anything about logging in Spring without getting a beginner's guide to getting started in Spring Boot, which is not what I want.

Right now Hibernate appears to respond to the contents of a logback configuration file being present, but oddly enough the rest of logging from Spring Boot does not.  Also the presence/absence of a log4j.xml file has no effect.

List of Dependencies is here.  Note, I did not design this, thanks.  Also, I'm used to running maven dependency-tree from intellij but that option is missing for some reason.

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.1.3.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-jcl:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-aop:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-expression:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-webmvc:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-aop:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-expression:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-web:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-tx:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.1.0.RELEASE
aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
org.springframework:spring-expression:3.0.6.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-aop:3.0.6.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.6.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-beans:3.0.6.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.6.RELEASE
org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:3.1.0.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.1.0.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.5.RELEASE
aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
org.springframework:spring-aop:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.1.0.RELEASE
aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
org.springframework:spring-expression:3.0.6.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-aop:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:3.0.6.RELEASE
org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:3.1.0.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:3.1.0.RELEASE
org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.1.0.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-tx:3.0.6.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-web:3.0.6.RELEASE
aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
org.springframework:spring-expression:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-aop:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.1.0.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-jdbc:3.0.6.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:3.1.0.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-tx:5.1.5.RELEASE
aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
org.springframework:spring-aop:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.1.0.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-web:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-expression:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-aop:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.1.0.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-context-support:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-beans:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-context:5.1.5.RELEASE
org.springframework:spring-core:5.1.5.RELEASE
javax.persistence:persistence-api:1.0.2
org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.6.10
javax.inject:javax.inject:1
javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5
javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:2.1
javax.servlet:jstl:1.2
javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.1.Final
javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.1.GA
com.fasterxml:classmate:0.8.0
org.sitemesh:sitemesh:3.0.0
net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1
commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4
commons-pool:commons-pool:1.5.4
javax.mail:mail:1.4
javax.activation:activation:1.1
org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.10
org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.10
commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
microsoft:reportingservices:1.0
org.apache.axis:axis:1.4
commons-io:commons-io:2.4
commons-discovery:commons-discovery:0.5
commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
javax.xml:jaxrpc-api:1.1
axis:axis-wsdl4j:1.5.1
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.7
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.7
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.7
com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.7
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.6
org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.10
commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10
junit:junit:4.7
```

Comment: Please provide your pom.xml ?

Comment: can you also provide your yaml configuration file, and some of the logs being generated?

Comment: @MuhammadInshal Sorry for an ignorant question, what makes you think there is a yaml file?